# How to use the WinRT SwapChainPanel control in a WPF window?

Tags: wpf, winapi, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, direct-composition

I added references to WinRT dlls to a WPF project and I want to use `SwapChainPanel` inside of a WPF window.
Is it really possible? For now I cant get it work.

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet package description for [Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls/) mentions a `SwapChainPanel` but I have not found any samples using this control in WPF.

> SwapChainPanel : Provides a hosting surface, where Microsoft DirectX swap chains provide content that can be rendered into a XAML UI. A SwapChainPanel element is a key component for an app that renders Microsoft DirectX graphics and then presents those visuals within a XAML page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently officially supported - might require some private APIs in Windows, though since Stardock could implement its ModernMix - there might be some way to get it working. The thing is though - you don't have to do that. You can render content with DirectX to a WPF window in other ways. I haven't done that and it might be quite a bit of work to do, but so is anything in DirectX. You can look into [DirectComposition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Perhaps the article on using [Direct2D with WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct-D-with-WPF) can be a good sample solution.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to, as says Filip Skakun, but you can ! Just give a try to **SlimDX** or **SharpDX**. They're DirectX's implementations in C#.

Comment: I don't think SlimDX or SharpDX allow you to put a WinRT `SwapChainPanel` control into a WPF app. They are C# wrappers for DirectX and while they might have helper classes or controls that are easy to host in window - that's not what the question was exactly about. Also there's another managed wrapper for DirectX 10-11 that I helped build a while back called [Windows API Code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) that is used in that Direct2D article. I'm not sure how long it will be available though since the code gallery page is being retired... tomorrow? :)

Comment: This is the best way I know. There is a SwapChain.